# Bash: find highest numerical value folder

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a folder with several numeric subfolders:

```
.
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
├── 4
└── 5_a
```

I would like to find the one with the highest value. In this example it would be folder 4.

The folders can also be numbered:

```
.
├── 1e-3
├── 2e-3
├── 3e-3
├── 4e-3
└── 5e-3_a
```

How can I achieve this? The code is to be used in a bash script for batch processing.

I have tried: `find . -type d -regex '.*/[0-9][^/]*' |sort -rn -t '\0' |head -n 1` but the regex syntax will not filter out exclusive numerical folders.

Best Regards

Comment: How can `4` be larger than `5_a`?

Comment: the `_a` would mean that the folder is not "numeric" anymore

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @anubhava. yes: `find . -type d -regex '.*/[0-9][^/]*' |sort -rn -t '\0' |head -n 1` . But this will not filter out the everything that is not exclusively a number

Comment: @PaulHodges. I will update the question...

Comment: Your 2nd example makes no sense given your first comment: "4e-3" is not numeric: what's the "highest" one?

Comment: Well,  that is scientific notation. It should be considered as valid

Answer (score 0):

I like extended globbing for things like this.

```
$: ls -ld *
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 1
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 2
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 3
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 5_e


$: shopt -s extglob   # turn on extended globbing
$: lst=( +([0-9])/ )  # get non-hidden directories named with only digits
$: echo ${lst[-1]%/}  # show the highest
4
```

## edit

Feeling stupid for posting that without correcting for lexical sorts...
Thanks, Glenn, for calling me on it.

Stealing some of @anubhava's logic to grab the **numeric** max, including the parsing of the scientific notation.

```
$: ls -ld *
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 1
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 2
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 10:13 2e-3
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 3
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 10:13 3e-3
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 10:13 4e-3
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 09:35 5_e
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 10:13 5e-3_a
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep  7 10:13 e-3


$: printf  '%s\0' +([0-9])*(e-[0-9])/ |
>   awk -v RS='\0' -F '/' '$1+0 > max {max = $1} END {print max}'
4
```

Comment: Take care: `lst` is sorted _lexically_ -- "10" comes between "1" and "2"

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `find | awk` command to find the greatest numerical value of a sub-directory name (gnu-awk will be required due to multi-char `RS`):

`awk` can handle scientific notation numerical strings as well.

```bash
find . -type d -name '*[0-9]*' -print0 |
awk -v RS='\0' -F '\\.?/' '
$NF+0 == $NF && $NF > max {max = $NF} END {print max}'

4
```

---

Or if all of your sub-directories at level 1 only, you may use this `printf | awk` solution:

```bash
printf '%s\0' *[0-9]*/ |
awk -v RS='\0' -F '/' '
$1+0 == $1 && $1 > max {max = $1} END {print max}'

4
```

Comment: Is `printf` better than `find`? Your previous code seemed to work nicely

Comment: Yes `find` will work fine as well but since all of your sub directories are at same level 1 only so I thought may be we can reduce command length.

Comment: Thanks! To see if I understand what is being done. You are getting all numerical folders, and looping through all of them. If the number of the folder + 0 = itself and is higher than max, it will take place as the new max. Folder that are not numeric when summed with 0 it will get be has having (5e-3 == 5e-3_a) which is false and thus not update the max.

Comment: Just a small detail. My terminal is complaining about the order of the options to find. It needs `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` before `-type`

Comment: Yes fixed `find` command. `5e+3` or `2e+2` will be treated as numeric value in `gnu-awk`. If you create a new directory with `mkdir 2e+2` then output will be `2e+2` instead of `4`. `$2+0 == $2` is a condition in `awk` that returns true if `$2` is numeric value.

Comment: An additional question if possible. In case the search directory is not the cwd wouldn't it be better to use `$NF` instead of `$2`?

Comment: Yes definitely and then we can remove `maxdepth/mindepth` options also. Check my edited answer and please mark as accepted if everything worked out